# Cannot access a disposed object server error while try to send data to remote device

Tags: c#, client-server

I am using `Client - Sever` application to received message from client, do my stuff and send back to the client message.

I am using `Server` and `Client` exapmle from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Sometimes during my tests i cannot connect my server and received the message that only one socket is allow and usually after the next successfully connection (after waiting 3 min) when the server try to send the message to the client my application crash in the server code with error:  `Cannot access a disposed object` in `Send` function:

```
handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
```

Maybe someone know why this happen ?

Comment: After many years, i haven't seen any solution to this except try/catch.

Comment: Why this is happening ?

Comment: This is because they close down the socket (resources), before the sending 'thread' is terminated.